# Angular route downloading a file instead of resolve a component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to download a file for a specific route?
`http://localhost:8080/my-route`

This URL would automatically download the file I want to serve.
All route examples found on the official angular website show how to link a route to a component..

EDIT

I would like to make this route `http://localhost:8080/my-route` doing a `GET` request to my backend and then downloads the file on the web browser

Comment: `The Angular Router enables navigation from one view to the next as users perform application tasks.` You could just load a component that doesn't have a template and, in the `ngOnInit`, do the `GET` call with its logic.

Comment: thanks i will try it